# Algorithm about playing animations of multiple objects

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project that instantiates 3d models on my scene and allows the user to play their animation on button click. However, in my current code, it only plays the animation of the first object it detects even tho there are other objects around. I want to play the animation of all objects on the scene. This is part of my current code. This is the method that will fire up once the button is clicked.

```
 public void PlayAnimation()
 {

     if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("3DObject).name.Contains ("Spidey"))
     {
         int spideyAnimation =  Random.Range(0, spideyAnimations.Length);
         GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("3DObject").GetComponent<Animation> ().Play (spideyAnimations[spideyAnimation]);

     }

     if (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("3DObject").name.Contains("Dino"))
     {
         int dinoAnimation =  Random.Range(0, dinoAnimations.Length);
         GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("3DObject").GetComponent<Animation> ().Play (dinoAnimations[dinoAnimation]);

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var arr = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("3DObject");
foreach (var o in arr) {
   if (o.name.Contains ("Spidey")) {
      // play spideyAnimation
   } else if (o.name.Contains ("Dino")) {
      // play dino animation
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current code will only find the first object, because you're calling GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag and not GameObject.FindGameObject**s**WithTag

[UnityDocs - GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)